# selecting last used name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a list of IDs and their corresponding names out of a table. Using

```
select distinct cast([ctID] as int), [ctName]
  FROM [tbl_CTResults]
```

I find that the name has changed over time. I have an additional column (`[statdate]`) that will allow me to know which is the latest name.

I tried using something like

```
SELECT cast([ctID] as int) ,max([statdate])

  FROM [InSightETL].[dbo].[tblPhWrk_WFM_iEX_CTResults] b
  group by cast([ctID] as int)

join 
SELECT * from (select distinct cast([ctID] as int)
      ,[ctName]
  FROM [InSightETL].[dbo].[tblPhWrk_WFM_iEX_CTResults] ) a
  on a.ctid=b.ctid
```

but apart from the fact the syntax is incorrect, the logic is also faulty. I know that I need to be able to select the correct record based on the date, but I can't figure out how to tie those two pieces of information together

Comment: Your title and your first line contradict each other.  Are you trying to get the latest changed name or a list of all names associated with a ctID?

Comment: @TTeeple, the first piece of code was my initial attempt. When I inspected the data, I found there were duplicates. That is what led to my 2nd mess of code, where I got a little stumped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
select cdid, ctName
from (select cast([ctID] as int) as ctid, [ctName],
             row_number() over (partition by ctID order by startdate desc) as seqnum
      FROM [tbl_CTResults]
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: +1 this is the standby. I just wish there were a way to mark every duplicate easily (this pattern comes up daily and the solution is always the same).

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . The problem with duplicates is that *we* know they are duplicates, but the person asking the question doesn't recognize the bigger picture.  StackOverflow is getting to the size where it probably needs a better classification algorithm for questions for suggesting similar questions.

Comment: Agreed, but critical mass is going to happen. I've literally stopped answering questions here because *every* question is a duplicate, with different column names and table names.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from 
 (
   select cast([ctID] as int), [ctName],
      row_number() over (partition by ctID order by statdate desc) as rn
   FROM [tbl_CTResults]
 ) as dt
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) (Common Table Expression):

```
;with cte (ctID, statdate)
as
(
    SELECT [ctID], max([statdate])
      FROM [InSightETL].[dbo].[tblPhWrk_WFM_iEX_CTResults]
      group by [ctID]
)
select cast(t.ctID as int), t.ctName
  from [InSightETL].[dbo].[tblPhWrk_WFM_iEX_CTResults] t
  join cte on cte.ctID = t.ctID and cte.statdate = t.statdate;
```

**NOTE:** This solution does not remove possible duplicate *statdate*'s for the same *ctID*.

Comment: It might have ties.  Unfortunately, the data type of `statdate` was not given (I assumed it's a datetime with the time part populated).

Comment: Thanks. Well noted.  I added it to the answer.

Comment: due to the data table being outside my control, **everything** is varchar(50)

Comment: @Sean tell the people who designed that table that they shouldn't be allowed to design tables.